# add before after, after a div ends

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a seperator after my div ends. I am thinking can we use it like we can use for the navigation menus and after li or before li.

can we add like that in my case?

[here's](http://jsfiddle.net/w4rmmvkc/1/) what I am trying.

```
    .content-wrapper .step1description p:after {

    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height:  5px; 
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Wrk0SFT.png); 
    top: 0; 
}
```

Will this work?

Please suggest a way to add the seperator If not this way.

Comment: You should try `border-bottom`

Comment: any reference of the same @VibhorDube

Comment: Are you looking to achieve something like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/zy3e4940/)

Comment: An image of what this is **supposed** to look like would be helpful here I think...it's not really clear what you are tryng to do.

Comment: my border is an image @vibhore.

 an image of dimension 250X50

Comment: @Suraj, Check this updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zy3e4940/1/), where I've removed the border and have used an image instead.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your `p` tag has the `.step1description` class (there is no p element under .step1description), so the correct declaration should be:

```
.content-wrapper .step1description:after {
...
}
```

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/w4rmmvkc/2/

Comment: hey thanks, but as I said I want it after the image, i.e. below the image

Answer (score 2):

I am not able exact what you are asking but I think you use this in your css class, Your code is working.

Css

```
.center-logo p.step1description::before {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

```css
.content-wrapper {

 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden; 
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #333230; 
}

.content-wrapper .center-logo {

 position: relative; width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 30px 0 15px 0;
}


.content-wrapper .center-logo img {

 display: inline-block; 
}

.content-wrapper .step1description{

 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 bottom: 24px;
 font-size: 10px;
}

 .content-wrapper .step1description:after {

  content: '';
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  height:  3px; 
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Wrk0SFT.png);  
       width:100%;
      bottom:0px;
      left:0;
      top:30px;
     
 }
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">

                <div class="container">
                    
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <div class="center-logo">

                                <img src="assets/description.png" alt="">
                                <P class = "step1description"> This is Testing </p>
                                        
                            </div>
                        
                        </div>  

                    </div>
                    
                </div>     

            </div>
```

Comment: This is not the way I want

Comment: you can change postion to 'left', 'right' 'bottom', 'top'   and height width according to your need. check the edited answer again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` on the `.step1description` (your css tried to reference any p that is child of `.step1description`)

Also change to `position:relative`, and `display:block`. This way, the line will be placed nicely between the image and the text inside the p.

```
.content-wrapper .step1description:before {

    content: '';
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
    height:  5px; 
    display: block;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Wrk0SFT.png); 
}
```